# Remove processing logs in Tesseract

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract C++ API for text detection in some images.

During the execution there are several log outputs, is there a way within the API to supress these logs?

Example:

```
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 1513
Estimating resolution as 863
Estimating resolution as 863
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set parameter `debug_file` to `/dev/null` (or some filename, where you can check warning from tesseract). See [tesseract user forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tesseract-ocr/Uqc6Y85nI8g/pgbapb2UCgAJ).

Comment: Yes thank you. This does indeed remove the tesseract logs, however I am still getting logs from leptonica calls. any inputs on that? thank you